# Formgroups and FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray, formgroups

From data that I recive from API I want to create a reactive form.
I have a formparent and multiple childforms. The data that I want to display in form looks like this:

```
    data{
    "extraInformation": false
    "cars": [
    {
     "Id": 48,  
    "Period": { 
    "Start": null, 
    "End": null }, 
    "Rentalstats": null, 
    "Reason": null 
    } 
    ]
    }
```

How do I achieve this?
So far this is what I have done:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({

    extraInformation: [this.data.ExtraInformation, [Validators.required]],
    cars: this.fb.array([this.addDetailFormGroup()]),
});

addDetailFormGroup() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    Reason: new FormControl(this.data?.cars?.Reason, Validators.required),
    Rentalstats: new FormControl(this.data?.cars?.Rentalstats, Validators.required),
    Period: new FormGroup([this.initListFormGroup()]),
  });
  initListFormGroup() {
    return new FormGroup({
      Start: new FormControl(this.data?.cars?.Period?.Start, Validators.required),
      End: new FormControl(this.data?.cars?.Period?.End, Validators.required),
    });
  }
```

But it dosent work because I get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Start')..

I would really appreciate it if someone could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would say that your code is not compilable as there are a few errors:

1. You are trying to re-assign the `FormGroup` instance with the form controls: `Reason`, `Rentalstats`, and `Period` that overwrite the original `FormGroup` with the form controls: `extraInformation` and `cars` array.
2. From the attached data, `this.data?.cars` is an array, you can't directly access `Reason` and other fields, but you need to iterate each element of the `cars` array, create `FormGroup` for each element and adding it into the `cars` `FormArray`.
3. `Period: new FormGroup([this.initListFormGroup()]),` This is not the proper way to assign the `FormGroup` instance to `Period` `FormGroup`. Your current code is trying to assign the value as `FormGroup` to a `FormGroup` control.
4. Incorrect way to declare `initListFormGroup` method. You should declare the method outside of `addDetailFormGroup` method.

The naming of the methods to create `FormGroup` is unclear/not meaningful, you should name it something like `initCarFormArray` and `initPeriodFormGroup` for better readability.

The component code to create the `form` and its nested `FormArray` and `FormGroup(s) should look as below:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    extraInformation: [this.data.extraInformation, [Validators.required]],
    cars: this.formBuilder.array([]),
  });

  this.initCarFormArray();
}

initCarFormArray() {
  for (let car of this.data.cars) {
    let carFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      Reason: new FormControl(car?.Reason, Validators.required),
      Rentalstats: new FormControl(car?.Rentalstats, Validators.required),
      Period: this.initPeriodFormGroup(car.Period),
    });

    this.cars.push(carFormGroup);
  }
}

initPeriodFormGroup(period: any) {
  return new FormGroup({
    Start: new FormControl(period?.Start, Validators.required),
    End: new FormControl(period?.End, Validators.required),
  });
}

get cars(): FormArray {
  return this.form.controls.cars as FormArray;
}
```

For the HTML to generate the `form`:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div>
    <span>ExtraInformation:</span>
    <input formControlName="extraInformation" />
  </div>

  <div formArrayName="cars">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let controls of cars.controls; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <div formGroupName="Period">
          <div>
            <span>Start:</span>
            <input formControlName="Start" />
          </div>

          <div>
            <span>End:</span>
            <input formControlName="End" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <span>Rentalstats:</span>
          <input formControlName="Rentalstats" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <span>Reason:</span>
          <input formControlName="Reason" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-huwyfp?file=src%2Fmain.html)

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thank you so much for your time and effort to help me out, works perfect!

Comment: @Young Shun Yong, I dont know if its ok to ask a followup question but I give it a go: I need to get the changes from the control that has changed to update API on blur. More  precisely I need the name of the array and the name of control in that array and the index of it, for exampe: cars[0].Reason". or cars[1].Period.Start". I also need the new value.  is that possible?

Comment: Seems like you are looking for `valueChanges` observable to check the form group is updated? Would be great that if you can post another question and specify the info in details. Thanks.